# Quantity update in cartReducer updates ItemReducer's item's quantity in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have two reducers `ItemReducer` where I am setting initially all the items which I am fetching using `Axios` calling `GET API`. Another reducer is `CartReducer` where I am storing cartItems.

**ItemReducer**

```
{
    item_id: '1',
    category_id: '12',
    item_name: 'Churros',
    item_image: 'item_081220170230.jpg',
    is_variant: '2',
    item_price: '9',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    currency_symbol: '$',
    item_quantity: '1',
    is_type: 'item'
}
```

**CartReducer**

```
{
    item_id: '1',
    category_id: '12',
    item_name: 'Churros',
    item_image: 'item_081220170230.jpg',
    is_variant: '2',
    item_price: '9',
    currency_code: 'USD',
    currency_symbol: '$',
    item_quantity: '1',
    is_type: 'item'
}
```

The problem is whenever I try to update `current` `cart` item's `quantity` it updates `itemReducer` item's quantity also I tried to use an `index` for catching exact item but not worked for me.
Here is the code.

```
const qtyChange = (item_id, variation_id) => {
     if (cartReducer.items){
       const {items} = cartReducer;
     if ( item_id && !variation_id ) {
       const filteredItem = items.filter(item => item.item_id === item_id).pop();
       filteredItem.item_quantity = Number( filteredItem.item_quantity ) + 1;
     } else{
       const filteredItem = items.filter(item => item.item_id === item_id && item.variation_id === variation_id).pop();
       filteredItem.item_quantity = Number ( filteredItem.item_quantity ) + 1;
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: All reducers are called when an action is dispatched and passes middleware. So if your action type is not unique then both reducers will act on the action.

Comment: @HMR first of all thanks for your reply I was totally disappointed that no one will give me a reply, the thing is reducers action is different in my case I am not sure what's the error because It's simply what we do in JS I am avoiding mutation of items.

Comment: You are mutating state though, unless you use the redux toolkit that inject immer in your reducers. Not sure why you would use `items.filter().pop()` and not just `items.find`. But even mutating the item would not change other state unless the other state is a reference to the item you are mutating.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I found where I am mistaking I am referencing `items` from `itemReducer` and adding new `items` to `cartReducer` need to check if fixed I will let you know.